# How to get weekday from timestamp in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, date

How can I get the week day for `20110828` (28th of August 2011)?
I've tried this, but it didn't work:

```
var date:Date=new Date(2011,8,28);
//Also tried var date:Date=new Date(20110828);
trace(date.day);//0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday etc
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that month 8 in AS is really month 9 in real life.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the [Date.getDay()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#getDay%28%29) method:

> Returns the day of the week (0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, and so on) specified by this Date according to local time. Local time is determined by the operating system on which the Flash runtimes are running.

Comment: Thanks David. `getDay()` and `day` do the same thing. I've figured out the problem though, I alwasy forget that months in AS are real-life months-1...

Comment: D'oh! I was, for some reason, under the impression that `.day` returned day-of-the-month.